# Error when building aosp for dragonboard 820c following linaros tutorial

Tags: android, android-source, dragonboard

My aim is to build aosp for dragonboard 820C. For this reason I followed the instruction on:

https://www.96boards.org/documentation/consumer/dragonboard/guides/aosp/

When I start building with " make -j$(nproc)". I receive following error. Do you have any hint or solution?

````
PLATFORM_VERSION=VanillaIceCream
PRODUCT_INCLUDE_TAGS=com.android.mainline
TARGET_PRODUCT=db820c
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=kryo
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=kryo
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.10.0-23-amd64-x86_64-Debian-GNU/Linux-11-(bullseye)
[ 87% 1064/1212] compile out/host/linux-x86/bin/go/soong-rust-config/pkg/android/soong/rust/config.a
0:03 compile out/host/linux-x86/bin/go/soong-android/test/android/soong/android.a
build/make/core/product.mk was modified, regenerating...
device/linaro/dragonboard/BoardConfigCommon.mk:28: warning: TARGET_USES_64_BIT_BINDER has been deprecated. All devices use 64-bit binder by 
default now. Uses of TARGET_USES_64_BIT_BINDER should be removed..
[100% 1213/1213] initializing legacy Make module parser ...
device/linaro/dragonboard/BoardConfigCommon.mk:28: warning: TARGET_USES_64_BIT_BINDER has been deprecated. All devices use 64-bit binder by 
default now. Uses of TARGET_USES_64_BIT_BINDER should be removed..
[ 99% 1387/1388] finishing legacy Make module parsing ...
FAILED: 
device/linaro/dragonboard/gralloc/Android.mk: error: "gralloc.gbm (native:vendor) can not link against libgbm (native:platform)" 
device/linaro/dragonboard/gralloc/Android.mk: error: "gralloc.gbm (native:vendor) can not link against libgbm (native:platform)" 
build/make/core/main.mk:1128: error: exiting from previous errors.
15:00:04 ckati failed with: exit status```
````